# Is it possible to split a String around "." in java?

Tags: java, string, split

When I try to split a String around occurrences of "." the method split returns an array of strings with length 0.When I split around occurrences of "a" it works fine.Does anyone know why?Is split not supposed to work with punctuation marks?

Comment: I recommend you read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes regex. Try `split("\\.")`.

Comment: Thought about closing as duplicate, but it's faster to answer :)

Comment: +1, or StringUtils.split -> http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split(java.lang.String,%20char)

Comment: They should have called it splitByRegex and keep a simple split method that takes a String ! Nearly every Java developer once lost time with this one... This would respect the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 2):

```
String a = "a.jpg";
String str = a.split(".")[0];
```

This will throw ArrayOutOfBoundException because split accepts regex arguments and "." is a reserved character in regular expression, representing any character.
Instead, we should use the following statement:

```
String str = a.split("\\.")[0]; //Yes, two backslashes
```

When the code is compiled, the regular expression is known as "\.", which is what we want it to be

Here is the link of my old blog post in case you are interested: http://junxian-huang.blogspot.com/2009/01/java-tip-how-to-split-string-with-dot.html